# Avoid column header during dataframe export to csv in a for loop

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, dictionary

In my situation, I export a `data frame` to a `.csv` file via a  `for loop`. The dataframe for each iteration is being created from a `list of dict`. The exported information is correct but of course, for every iteration, headers are displayed in the `csv` file.

Here is the code snippet:

```
f = open("Test" + ".csv", "w+")
for junc in Junctions:
        conn = model.connections(Junction = junc)  #list(dict)
        DF4dictConn = pd.DataFrame(conn)           #convert to DF
        DF4dictConn['Junction'] = junc  # Add a new column
        DF4dictConn.set_index('Junction',inplace=True)  #set the new column as index
        DF4dictConn.to_csv(f,sep=',')  #export dataframe for each junction
```

The output of the `.csv` file is shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to avoid the repetition of the headers ***but only display the header once?***

Conn:

[image]

Comment: Actually it seems a bit odd, that you write the `.csv` each iteration. Wouldn't it be better to build a proper DataFrame first and then write the ``.csv` file once?

Comment: Yes, @SimonFink I did that first but I had issues in building an entire list(dict) and eventually converting it to a dataframe in one go. Is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: Checkout `DataFrame.append()` function. So you can iterate over your Junctions and build one single DataFrame.

Comment: updated with an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) of `DataFrame.to_csv()` you need to set the `header` flag. So instead, try:

```
DF4dictConn.to_csv(f,sep=',', header=False)  #export dataframe for each junction
```

If you want to display the header in the first iteration of the loop, please refer to this nice [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927544/for-loop-first-iteration) about how to implement the **Head-Tail design pattern**.

Comment: Hi Simon, apologies I just updated the query. I would like to get the header displayed just once as the first row.

Comment: Added an article for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @user11397513 then create a flag for first iteration and include the header for that

Comment: Hard to guess, as I don't know how `junc` and `conn` look like.