# Pythonic way to assign variable before entering for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-3.8, walrus-operator

I am iterating over a list of strings and matching whether the target version of last string matches current version of present string.

My solution to this problem is:

```
regex_pattern = r"^(\w+)-to-(\w+)\.bat$"
script_list = ["v1-to-v2.bat", "v2-to-v3.bat", "v3-to-v4.bat", "v5-to-v6.bat", "v6-to-v7.bat"]
first_script_match = re.match(regex_pattern, script_list[0])
temp_script = first_script_match.group(0)
temp_version = first_script_match.group(2)
for script in script_list[1:]:
    script_match = re.match(regex_pattern, script)
    if (from_version := script_match.group(1)) != temp_version:
        print(
            f"Target version {temp_version} of last script {temp_script} does not "
            f"match current version {from_version} of current script {script}"
        )
    temp_script = script_match.group(0)
    temp_version = script_match.group(2)
```

which is similar to the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927544/for-loop-first-iteration) question.

I was wondering if there is a more pythonic solution to this problem that does not pollute the module's namespace as much. I know about the walrus operator that has been introduced in Python 3.8 for the same purpose, but I'm not sure if I can use it in a for loop.

Comment: as for me more pythonic would be to set `from_version =...` before `if` (without `:=`) because it would be more readable.

Comment: I personally don't feel using walrus operator reduces readability if you know about it. In case you don't know about walrus operator, it can be rather confusing though.

Comment: I know walrus since it was introduced in 3.8 (I even created few examples on my blog)  but I never saw any code which would use it :)